# Git : managing the config files on the master/staging

Tags: spring, git, github

This may be obvious to some and I have been trying to maintain config files for the spring application. I have spring.xml and springpath.xml so the content is different for each production and dev environment.

When I merge master to my dev branch that merges nicely and then commit the code. Create a pull request for GitHub, at this stage both config files get merged and I end up having dev config files into the master branch too, which is bit annoying.

Is there a better to handle this, please?

thanks

Comment: I come across adding a git attribute file on the project root with the following line,   db.xml merge=ours   This isn't working for me. Is this even a right solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved similar issue by using the Spring Cloud Config, where i have different configuration is maintained for development, staging and production.

All the config are maintained in git (not Github; but definitely not a killer difference). Spring Cloud Config server and config client can help you to get the configuration from git server based on profile that you supply when running the app.

Note:
Since i am using Spring boot, things were really smooth and easy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion, the project I'm working this wouldn't be a good fit as the project isn't based on the spring boot.